# Как определить, есть ли здесь рекурсия?

Tags: рекурсия, ssi

Объясните, есть ли здесь рекурсия. Где именно?
И можно ли ее победить в данном случае?

```
$stat = file_get_contents('constant2.html');
$our_var = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die("Could not connect");
$var_key = @$memcache_obj->get($our_var);
if(!empty($var_key))
    {echo $var_key;}
else    {$memcache_obj->set($our_var, $stat, false, 2629743);
        echo $memcache_obj->get($our_var);}
$memcache_obj->close();
```

Я получаю ошибку:

> [error]: subrequests cycle while processing "/css/constant.html" while
>   sending to client, client: 60.240.60.50, server: site.ru, request:
>   "GET /css/print.css HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/css/constant.html",
>   upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/constant.html", host: "site.ru",
>   referrer: "http://site.ru/"

И пытаюсь понять, чем она вызвана.

Если по-русски...

1. Получаю название ***текущего файла*** (запрошенного браузером пользователя) в переменную `$our_var: basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`
2. и использую эту переменную в качестве ключа объекта в кэше для вывода на ***текущую страницу*** html кода, "положенного" в объект memcache

Объект в кэше есть. Ключ в переменной тоже. 
Но я все равно получаю ошибку.

Comment: Наталья, вы открыли новый тип программистов - SO программист, который на любую свою проблему сразу открывает вопрос на SO и не пытается думать самостоятельно. Вполне вероятно, что вы пытаетесь через `file_get_contents` получить содержимое той же страницы, в которой вызываете `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Ну, вот, такой я программист с экономическим образованием. Учиться приходится сразу на практике. Увы. А для того, чтобы думать в этом направлении, мне, к сожалению, базы не хватает:( От мозга уже четверть осталась. Стихи + музыку мне легче писать, чем код. Через file_get_contents я пытаюсь получить ssi-инклюд, который и хочу получать из кэша, не "трогая" файлы на сервере. Ибо получение их из файлов на каждой странице приводит к превышению лимитов хостинга и 508 ошибке.

Comment: Вы вообще читали, что такое рекурсия? Откуда ей здесь взяться?

Comment: Читала. И пыталась понять, что это и откуда в данном коде. Поиск по подобным ошибкам (subrequests cycle while....) выдавал именно решения с рекурсией. И в заголовке вопроса, если Вы обратили внимание, этот вопрос и наличествует. Учусь пока, причем вынужденно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если прочитать справку по memcache_set https://www.php.net/manual/ru/memcache.set.php то можно увидеть, что время хранения не может быть больше 2592000 и если пытаться указать больше, то время хранения объекта в кэше сразу истекает и он удаляется.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсии тут, видимо, нет. 
Задача решилась весьма неожиданым образом. Может быть, кому-нибудь пригодится эта информация.

**вместо Memcache используется Memcached**

Систематизированной информации по данному вопросу в сети немного. А такой, чтобы мог понять человек, не изучавший усиленно сей предмет, вообще практически нет.

Как раз в моем случае все получилось заменой на:

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcached();

$memcache_obj->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

Удачи всем!